# How to parse & update a flat file using UNIX script

Tags: file, shell, unix, flat

I am trying to parse a flat file which has columns by the titles 
`NAME COMPANY DETAILS STATUS etc` (where the data is dissimilar among itself).

I need to update the `STATUS` column when I run a script with that file as input, with the STATUS being updated depending on other columns' details.

sed & vi cannot be used, as obvious. Please help.

An excerpt of the file that I am trying to parse is :
an excerpt from the file I am trying to parse, for which the question is asked, is :

34 /*   1       2       3       4       5       6
35 /*3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
36   YYNNN LOCAL1           TRANSFER-CDM(only) =>local.transfer         LOCAL
37   YYNNN LOCAL2       EXCHANGE-CATIA =>IGES/DXF/STEP              LOCAL
38   YYNNN ACIS1    C   AutoWeb Media Services                  CCX
39   YYNNN ACNC1    C   Auto/Con Corporation                    CCX
40   YYNNN ACST1    C   Accurcast Inc                       CCX
41   YYNNN AAGD1    C   Algonquin Automotive                    CCX

---

Now what I need to do is to parse this flat file and the 6th column would be added as STATUS.

I have tried:

### awk '/23861/ { $0=$0 "|Processed" } {print}' input

where - 1.awk command wil srch 4 the pattern
        2.that thng in curly brackets will update in last column

But this too is giving me error :
 it is adding the column at the end with the "|Processed" string if it matches the string in the line.
If I run that command again, it adds again that string at the end.
That row looks like
JAN FEB MAR |Processed |Processed

Now, what I want is to replace that previous “|Processed” value with the new one(as per the condition)  and update that value accordingly

Comment: can you show a sample of the file. It could be possible with awk, but how do we know what to look for??

Comment: One more doubt about the string pattern mentioned in the command..

The string pattern is mentioned in /PATTERN/.
It is taking the actual string in it. But, it is not taking a variable as the input
Like if I put a variable mailbox in it as /$mailbox/, it is not giving the output as expected...

Answer (score 1):

You should define

> depending on other columns' details.

what details??

e.g.  if DETAILS column value ==1 then do the update, you can do:

```
awk '$3==1{$4="NEW STATUS"}1' yourFlatFile
```

if you want to check, if the name of company contains "google", you do the update:

```
awk '$1~/google/{$4="NEW Status"}1' flatFile
```

you have to define the **details** of other columns.

Comment: Please see the updated question string...

Comment: and what if if I want the google string stored in a variable ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
cat flatfile | awk '{ $4 = "New Status"; print }'
```

Comment: but it will update the whole 4th column for the whole file; i need to update the STATUS depending upon a specific row's content as shown by the rest of the columns...

Comment: Please see the updated question string...

Comment: I was tempted to edit this to `awk '{ $4 = "New Status"; print }' flatfile` because the cat here is superfluous, but I figure it works fine. It is sort of a peeve of mine to call additional executables when none is necessary.